# Different trend lines obtained when using abline(lm(y~x)) versus stat_smooth(method=lm)

Tags: r, plot

I am getting different trend lines when I use:

```
plot(x=time,y=eat)
abline(lm(eat~time))
```

versus

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=time,y=eat)) + geompoint()+ stat_smooth(method=lm,se=TRUE)
```

Why is there a difference in the two trend lines when plotted using different methods?

Is there a way to calculate the slope of the lines obtained via `stat_smooth`?

When I plot the line using the slope/intercept obtained from `summary(lm(eat~time))`, it does not match with the line obtained from `stat_smooth`

Comment: Can you please give a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks, the typo was made in only reproducing the question here. I have corrected it above

Comment: When I try with `mtcars`, I get identical looking results. Can you provide a reproducible example? Also, it appears you've `attach`ed your data, which is risky. Are you sure the vectors `eat` and `time` in your workspace still match the corresponding columns of `data`?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) for tips on making reproducible examples. You should share data (in order of preference) 1. using built-in data, 2. simulating (with a random seed), 3. actual data using `dput()`.

Comment: Thank you will look into it.